# Type mismatch when checking cells for error

Tags: vba, excel

```
    If Cells(i, 4).Value = xlErrNA Then
        MsgBox ("Error on row " & i)
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

I think I'm setting up this if statement wrong. I also tried with "#N/A" and got the same failure. Any guidance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An error type cannot be compared to a string/numeric type, because they are two different *types* of data.

First, you need to check for error:

```
If IsError(Cells(i, 4).Value) Then
    If Cells(i, 4). Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
        MsgBox ("Error on row " & i)
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Note that the `IsError` will test for *any* error value, while your `= xlErrNA` **only** checks for the specific error: `#N/A`.  The `CVErr` function converts the enumerated constant `xlErrNA` (which is a long/numeric value) to its error-type equivalent.

You may need to add other conditions for other error types `#REF!"` `#Name!`, etc., or you could simply omit the `If Cells(i, 4). Value = xlErrNA` and then this will handle *any* error values.

```
If IsError(Cells(i, 4).Value) Then

        MsgBox ("Error on row " & i)
        Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket on the first line after `.Value` ;)

Comment: Noted, and fixed :) @Gareth

Comment: The enum comparison would still fail I think, instead `If Cells(i, 4).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IsError` function to check if the cell contains an error like so:

```
If IsError(Cells(i, 4).Value) Then
    MsgBox ("Error on row " & i)
    Exit Sub
End If
```